# How to iterate dblookup sql result?

Tags: wso2-esb

How do i iterate SQL result if result is more than one row.
I want read all rows values from a given table(Ex: select * from employee )
Below is the sample code.

```
<dblookup>
            <connection>
                <pool>
                    <password>root123</password>
                    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ESB_SP_LOANS</url>
                    <user>root</user>
                </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
                <sql><![CDATA[select * from TableName]]></sql>
            </statement>
</dblookup>
```

Comment: Some time ago I developed a custom mediator that can read multiple records from a database and adds them to the current message context as the current body. Is rather limited, but gets the job done for simple scenarios. 

For anything more complex than a simple lookup-like query that returns a few records, I´d sugest to use DSS or a dedicated backend.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/DBLookup+Mediator

The DBLookup mediator can set a property from one row in a result set. It cannot return multiple rows